# How to share folders between host and guest in VMware?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm using the following set up:

Host: Windows 10. Guest: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. VMware Workstation 12 player (free edition).

I've enabled the sharing folders option on the host as shown in the picture below:

[image]

however, while browsing the guest filesystem I cannot find the shared folder nor the mounting options. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This shares an *existing* host folder, which is then browsable from the VM. That is, it shares a host folder to a guest, not a guest folder to a host. You're expected to create the host folder yourself; there is nothing special to 'browse' to on the host side.

Comment: @Bob sorry, I meant the GUEST filesystem. Essentially, on Ubuntu I cannot find the shared folder. I already created the folder on the host.

Comment: You should look into "network" as this shared folders are typically presented to the guest OS as network shares. Or read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools